# Coloring cell in AG-Grid depending on it's content by using justpy web framework

Tags: python, ag-grid, justpy

I encountered a problem using AG-Grid in combination with justpy web framework.

[JustPy](https://justpy.io/) is an object-oriented, component based, high-level Python Web Framework that requires no front-end programming. With a few lines of only Python code, you can create interactive websites without any JavaScript programming.

I want to **change the color of a cell into the grid depending on it's value**.
The grid consists of 22 columns with several rows. The initialization of the grid is as follows:

```py
#table Analysis
gridAnalysis = jp.AgGrid(style=styleTableAnalysis, a=divTableAnalysisdata)
```

I found a solution for JS on the official AG-Grid documentation [JavaScript Data Grid: Cell Styles](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/cell-styles/). In this documentation, the variant of using the Cellstyle and the CellClassRule are listed. With the **Cellstyle** I can **only change the color of the whole column** and **not a special cell**. The **CellClassRule** doesn't work at all bc I **can't include the JS for that rule by using justpy**.

Here is my approach for coloring the cells depending on it's value

```py
#list with dict for the data of two rows
gridAnalysisRowContent = [
    {'C': 0.0206, 'Si': 0.003, 'Mn': 0.079, 'P': 0.007, 'S': 0.005, 'Al': 0.0, 'N2': 0.0, ...}, 
    {'C': 0.053, 'Si': 0.011, 'Mn': 0.851, 'P': 0.009, 'S': 0.0025, 'Al': 0.032, 'N2': 0.0, ...}
]

#turn list into pandas dataframe
gridAnalysisRowContentDF = pd.json_normalize(gridAnalysisRowContent)
            
#load dataframe data into the grid
gridAnalysis.load_pandas_frame(gridAnalysisRowContentDF)

#list for the keys of the dicts from list gridAnalysisRowContent
keys = ['C', 'Si', 'Mn', 'P', 'S', 'Al', 'N2', ...]

#iteration for coloring the cells depending on the cell value.
#if the value is less than the maximum value, the cell should be colored
for row in gridAnalysisRowContent:      #iteration for the two rows
    for k in range(len(keys)):          #iteration for the keys
        element = keys[k]               #current element
        maxValue = 0.5                  #max value
        contentElement = row[element]   #value of the current element
        if contentElement < maxValue:
            #coloring the cell
            gridAnalysis.options['columnDefs'][k]['cellStyle'] = {'background-color': 'lightblue'}
```

This works fine but it colors the whole column and not the separate cell.

How can I color a cell depending on its content?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

I found a solution to color single cells of an AG-Grid in combination with justpy web framework.

For that solution I used the **[CellClassRule](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/cell-styles/)** propertie of the AG-Grid. You just need to add a cellClassRules propertie to the columnDefs of the cell you want to change it's backgroundcolor depending on it's own value. The code below shows an small example.

```py
import justpy as jp
import pandas as pd

#list with dict for the data of two rows
gridAnalysisRowContent = [
  {'C': 0.0206, 'Si': 0.003, 'Mn': 0.079, 'P': 0.007, 'S': 0.005, 'Al': 0.0, 'N2': 0.0}, 
  {'C': 0.053, 'Si': 0.011, 'Mn': 0.851, 'P': 0.009, 'S': 0.0025, 'Al': 0.032, 'N2': 0.0}
]

#turn list into pandas dataframe
gridAnalysisRowContentDF = pd.json_normalize(gridAnalysisRowContent)

def grid_test():
  wp = jp.WebPage() #create wp
  gridAnalysis = jp.AgGrid(a=wp)  #create grid

  #turn list into pandas dataframe
  gridAnalysisRowContentDF = pd.json_normalize(gridAnalysisRowContent)
              
  #load dataframe data into the grid
  gridAnalysis.load_pandas_frame(gridAnalysisRowContentDF)

  #iterate through all columnDefs
  for column_defs in gridAnalysis.options['columnDefs']: 
    maxValue = 0.05 #set max value
    minValue = 0.02 #set min value
    #define the cellClass Rules (only works with background color as tailwindcss class)
    column_defs['cellClassRules'] = {
      'bg-red-300': 'x > {max}'.format(max = maxValue), #set background color to red if cell value is greater than maxValue
      'bg-blue-300': 'x < {min}'.format(min = minValue) #set background color to blue if cell value is smaller than minValue
    }
  return wp

jp.justpy(grid_test)
```

***Notice:*** the cellClassRule propertie only works with the background color as [tailwindcss](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-color) class in this example *'bg-red-300'* and *'bg-blue-300'*. The *x* represent the cell value.

Answer (score -3):

Are you using AdapTable with AG Grid?

If so then you can use their Conditional Styling which will style cells based on their values using whichever rules you provide.

See:  https://docs.adaptabletools.com/guide/handbook-conditional-styling

Comment: Clarification should be requested in comments, not in answers.

Comment: thanks for the quick response, but I think I can't use AdapTable with ag-grid in the justpy web framework.  I edited my question and added some code. Maybe my problem is more clear now.